# Locking a PhoneGap Android app with a PIN code

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, privacy

I'm using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) to build an app. I'd like for it to lock itself with a PIN-code (it has to be an in-app lock, separate from the native Android lock) in the following cases:

- A certain amount of time has passed with no user input
- The user navigates away from the app, for example if the app is minimized or if the phone is left laying around for a while and the screen turns off.

Questions:

- I'm assuming the the phone timing out and turning off the screen will trigger the [pause event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause), but is that really how it works?
- Is it possible to run a `setInterval()` function to run even when the phone is "paused" in order to check with a server to push [notifications](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)? I'm interested in Android only, I know iOS has some quirks.
- Finally, what is the best way to go about implementing a PIN-lock? Overlay the current interface or redirect the app to a "lock page," while remembering the original page or something?

Comment: 1. yes, or when they come back. 2. yes, depending on the launchMode of the app. 3. use a modal dialog.

Comment: Depending on the screen flow of your app, you may need to also disable the back button functionality to prevent the user from "escaping" your lock modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have any code examples, but I can discuss a theoretical implementation.

I would personally implement the locking screen, at the opening of the app.  To maintain consistency that the app is a PIN based app (awful wording I know).  So whenever the app is first open, it should ask for the pin number.

When Implementing the redirection, I would use the Back Method to go backwards (DevExtreme has a default back method, I'm not sure if phonegap has one or not)

Attempt to access the back method, if it fails. Proceed forward.

Accomplish this using a try/catch, try to go back, if it errors assume its erroring because there is no where to go back to. Proceed to home screen.

Implement the onPause method to move to the lock screen after the device pauses.

if you don't have a default back method heres a mock up on implementing one using pseudo code

in order to create the mockup we're gonna hijack the the navigation method, or better yet we're gonna recreate the navigation method, but still use the existing method.

```
define backstring = ""

function NavigateTo(string navigateto)
    backstring = currentnavigationscreen
    this.Navigate(navigateto)
end
```

this method sets the value of the backstring and navigates to the next screen

```
function GoBack()
    NavigateTo(backstring)
end
```

this is what the onpause method should look like

```
function onPause()
    NavigateTo("lockscreen")
end
```

I certainly hope that this helps.

Instead of doing a try and catch on the back function, you chould also create a CanBack() method.

```
function CanBack()
    return (backstring.length > 0)
end
```

Quote

> Depending on the screen flow of your app, you may need to also disable
>   the back button functionality to prevent the user from "escaping" your
>   lock modal. –  Garcia Hurtado

This is an excellent point, however if you stick with the pseudo-code I gave and don't connect it to the back button mechanism you will be fine.  Just make sure when you navigate to the password screen, you treat it as the root.

You could also create an overlay, and simply maintain a boolean that determines whether to display it or not. The default value could be true, so every time the app is opened you have to enter the passcode.  And you can use the onpause function to set the boolean to false to inform the app that it needs to be locked again.

Comment: I recently developed an app using devexpress and ran into the same issue, so I had most of details already sorted. Feel free to ask if you need any help with the implementation.

Comment: Hi Cody. I need to lock my app via PIN. App is in sencha touch. If u can help me, it would be great. Just guide me from where start implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

1) the pause event is triggered whenever the screen goes off or the app is minimized you can use the pause event for creating a lock on your screen. You may also require to disable the bwck button in this case, so user doesnt navigate to previous page when you show the lock screen.

2) it is possible to run the setinterval function on the pause event so whenever your phone is paused you make communication with the server.
Here is some code:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
function onPause() { // Handle the pause event
setInterval( function() {
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://convert4mobile.net/backend/API/qr/push.php',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    if (typeof plugins !== "undefined") {
              window.plugins.localNotification.add({
                        date : new Date(),
                        message : data.time+"\r\n"+data.msg,
                        ticker : "A new code was generated",
                        repeatDaily : false,
                        id : 4
                });
                }
                }
            }
           });
} , 2000);
}
```

3) if it just about a screen which will not let the user interact with the app without entering correct pin, then it should be an overlay. You can use a saperate screen as well, but using a modal overlay with the message to enter pin with disabling the back button at the same time is enough. So you dont get stuck into your pages while redirecting.

Comment: I am just wondering if the lock screen is just an html5 overlaying layer, does it mean it can be easily removed if the device is rooted and pulled from the source code, or would it be no difference if it is written in Native Java?